# Why is an Event happening properly in GWT Development Mode but not outside?

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I have a SmartGWT List Grid. In the constructor of a GWTP view I add a DataArrivedHandler to this List Grid to select the first record, obtain data from that record and then use it to populate a couple of StaticTextItems.

In GWT Development mode it works perfectly. Outside of GWT Development mode (i.e. the "normal" way) it doesn't work. There are no errors being reported in the GWT console.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the "classic" dev mode or super dev mode?

Probably a bug related to some timing issue, e.g. the event gets added before the element is attached to the DOM or something like that.

Try putting your event handler setup stuff in the onAttach() method part of the widget, might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with GWTP, the view is not the right place to initialize the widgets. You should initialize it in onBind() method from presenter. Maybe this is the problem.

Remember that [Presenters have a fixed life cycle!](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Presenter-Lifecycle)